# How to get document (seo) title of specific page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I don't mean the page or post title but the title between `<title>` and `</title>`. The so-called SEO or document title.

I've just googled but found nothing. I only know to get document title of current page we can use `wp_get_document_title()`. But how to get document title of specific page by its post or category ID for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if we use Yoast we can get the document title by the following line:

```
$seo_title = get_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_title', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_the_title()` or `the_title()`, depending in which context you need it. No Yoast needed.

Details here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/

Comment: See again my question: `I don't mean the page or post title but the title between <title> and </title>. The so-called SEO or document title.`

Comment: It's a confuse of WP: post or page title must be called **heading** and not so general term as **title**